# Negating a regex pattern match

Tags: perl, if-statement, conditional-statements, inverse

Is there a way to negate the elsif statement with the following pattern match statement, something like `$ip != $testip`?

I know that `!=` is only for integers, I just wanted to explain what I want: the same function as `!=` but for strings when pattern matching.

```
if ( $testip =~ /$ip/ ) {
    $frequency++;
}
elsif ( $ip ne $testip ) {
```

Comment: `ne` is the negation of `eq`. What's the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To negate matching, you can use

```
$testip !~ /$ip/
```

but there's no need to know, you can just negate the operator

```
not $testip =~ /$ip/
```

But why? The `else` branch is only executed when the `if` condition returns false.